# Woocommerce - Change Variable Product Add to Cart to behave like external product using Custom Field (link)

Tags: plugins, custom-field, templates, e-commerce, woocommerce-offtopic

I am importing affiliate products via XML into Woocommerce. Due to products having variations if I use the External/Affiliate product type I get repetition of product on my front end (eg. same product with different location/colour). To avoid this I am attempting to import these products as variable products, this solves the problem, except now I need to Change the add to cart to behave like an external product (i.e. a Button that links to another website).

I've created a Custom Value associated with each product called "Buy_Link", now what?

I have searched and searched, but unable to find a solution for something I thought would be relatively simple for someone with php knowledge.

I know that I should be able to retrieve the link doing something like this:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Buy_Link', true); ?>
```

(After some help and a bit more searching) I believe I will need to place code: 
    ID, 'Buy_Link', true); ?>

into single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php, but I am still unsure where it would go in that template.

I would like the link to replace some of the functionality of the original add to cart button.

Obviously, I am not too familiar with php code, so please be specific about how and where in the template I can put the code. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for adding a custom field to EACH variation, in case someone is looking for this solution, there is a tutorial here (thanks Derek!):

http://designloud.com/how-to-add-affiliate-links-to-woocommerce-variations/

I spent weeks trying to find a solution for this - Hope this saves someone some time :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the solution. This is so simple and I can't believe I did not just do this first, but there you are (duh), I thought it was more complex than that...

My solution is below:

Copy woocommerce template to my theme to override single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php

editing variables.php, change the

```
<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>
```

to the below (replace by calling my custom field url):

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Buy_Link', true); ?>
```

Anyway, this works a treat to get the link to the buy button (and bypasses the cart altogether) but still allowing variations to be shown. 
Now I just need to get a custom field for EACH variation instead of only one custom field per variable product (didn't realise this limitation)! Then I can have the appropriate link for EACH variation, not just default product variation.

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: The `add_to_cart_url()` is also filterable.

Answer (score 0):

You got the exact code to display WordPress custom field. I'm not accustomed to WooCommerce, but I can say the WordPress way, and guess WooCommerce won't be different as they all are actually go with the logic of coding.

The following code is just to show (PHP `echo`) the field "`Buy_Link`", but it doesn't fetch the field from database. So before that code, you have to fetch the associated data from the database first.

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Buy_Link', true); ?>
```

In the WordPress way, we typically do that using [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts%E2%80%8E) (accidentally with [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts%E2%80%8E)). And after that, you have to put that after the `the_post()` function.

But with a WP_Query, the `the_post()` function would be like `$query->the_post()`, if we go like this:

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish');

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if($query->have_posts()){
   while($query->have_posts()) {
     $query->the_post(); //is actually placing the post information here ?>
     <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
     <div><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Buy_Link', true); ?></div>
   <?php
   } //endwhile
} //endif
?>
```

Just observe that, we are doing a **new** `WP_Query()` with some argument, and then checking that **if** there is any post as we queried? Then we started a PHP `while loop` passing the same query, and the saying, show `the_post()` only from that query using `$query->` before. And this `$query` is fetching data from the database.

So, in summery, you have to put the aforementioned code of showing custom field within a database query.

Comment: I believe I will need to place code: `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Buy_Link', true); ?>` into single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php, but I am still unsure where it would go in that template since I would like the link to replace some of the functionality of the original add to cart button. I am afraid queries and loops are all very confusing to me. (Sorry about the double comment)